# How to trigger an action in viewDidAppear only the first time a view controller is shown?

Tags: ios, swift

Essentially I would like to print the following "hello" message only once when the view appears only the first time when the app first loads. The ViewController can be shown again when a tab in a tab controller triggers it, but it should not print the message after the very first time. Going back to the ViewController should not trigger this "hello" to print.

**The following is what I have already tired, but it does not seem to work?**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if self.isBeingPresented || self.isMovingToParent {
        print("hello")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most stable way is

```
var once = true

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated) 
    if once {
        print("hello")
        once = false
    }
}
```

As `self.isBeingPresented || self.isMovingToParen` can give unexpected results according to where you use it

Comment: I appreciate your help, I have a separate question regarding textField, can you please have a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56876794/how-to-display-a-microphone-icon-in-a-textfield-that-triggers-dictation-when-pre